# How to keep variable value if new value is None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to assign values to a bunch of variables. If the value is None, the variable should stay put, but if there is a value, it should get assigned. The obvious way is

```
if v is not None:
    x = v
```

but repeating this construct over and over again uglifies the code. Doing this works

```
 x = v if v is not None else x
```

but it does an unnecessary assignment operation and this is a frequently executed code path.

Is there a better way? Or does python optimize something like this and there is no assignment?

Comment: I understand the reasoning but it really feels like a trivial optimisation. In the scope or Python, I really don't think there is ground to be gained here

Comment: `x = v or x`? may also work.

Comment: @DavidZemens I honestly think it is more readable in an `if; else` construct, although I do think you're right.

Comment: The second construct I mentioned was flagged on the code review as unnecessary variable assignment. Not trying to over-optimize, just trying to get my code approved :)

Comment: I think the `if; else` construct might be the only way to go. I can't think of any better way.

Comment: I mean you don't need the `else x` which is probably why it was flagged.

Comment: @d_kennetz sure, matter of opinion. I prefer the ternary statement (second option) 
 personally, just tossing this out there as another possibility for this case.

Comment: *I need to assign values to a bunch of variables* and your repeatedly running in to this sort of if/else condition during this task, this seems like there's a better way to solve the problem via design, but it's not really clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: also, if you find yourself doing the same thing over and over again in your code, abstract it out to its own function, and replace the ugly code with function calls.

Comment: `if v is not None` is PEP8 best practice here. If your code has a bunch of trivial `if/else` calls for variable assignments then there is probably something better to be done upstream.

Comment: Don't worry about this unless it's actually causing a performance problem. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Most of the time the difference is negligible. Write it in the way that's most clear to the reader, worry about performance later if necessary.

Comment: As I said, I am not worried about performance. I am trying to get people to accept my coding style.

Comment: If you have *MANY* such statements in a single place, perhaps what you really want is actually a `dict` or even a [`defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `dis` module, we can examine the assembled python.

```
import dis

def a(v):
    if v is not None:
        x = v
def b(v):
    x = v if v is not None else x
```

It would appear that the second method is actually slightly faster, although extremely marginally.

```
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (v)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12
              8 LOAD_FAST                0 (v)
             10 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 14)
        >>   12 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
        >>   14 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(b)
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (v)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12

  5           8 LOAD_FAST                0 (v)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

That being said, pick whatever is more readable, or more accepted.  I don't think two instructions is noticeable on any scale.